# make the webpage fit into the screen

Tags: html, css

Trying to make the webpage fit into the screen so that you don't have to scroll up or down, or left and right. And the image is centered. Here is the current code:

```css
#copyright {
  top: 0px;
  right: 11;
  z-index: index 1;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2;
  width: 2;
  z-index: index 2;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://lensdump.com/i/rSRDHc">
  <img id="image" src="https://i3.lensdump.com/i/rSRDHc.png" alt="rSRDHc.png" border="0" /></a>

<div id="copyright"> ©apple </div>
```

Comment: what has this question to do with visual studio code? Also post an actual title not the tags.

Comment: To make a website to always fit the viewport without overflow you have to insure that the content is less then even the tiniest screen which is a silly attempt in the first place. Your image is quite large and needs to be seriosly downsized. Easier would be to work with a small SVG or icon that can be upsized or downsized and has no massive white space like your image.

Comment: You need to clearly explain the problem. Saying Im trying blah blah blah... isn't a question about a specific problem. Also, you need to include debugging information, or explain how you attempted to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Overflow wouldn't work if you wanted to scroll down to show more of the page. To fix that, you would have to crop the white background out of the image, which I'm unsure of why it's there in the first place, and it would also be best to make the background transparent after you crop it, in case you wanted to change the background colour.

You had the right set to 11, but didn't specify a value (same as your width and height on the image), which doesn't work at all; you have to specify a value e.g pixels or rem. And z-index: *index* [num] also isn't valid, it's just z-index: [num].

The alt tag on your image is a png file, which doesn't make much sense, it should be a description, or the link to the image.

```css
#copyright {
  right: 11px;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.7);
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<a href="https://lensdump.com/i/rSRDHc">
  <img id="image" src="https://i3.lensdump.com/i/rSRDHc.png" alt="rSRDHc.png" border="0" /></a>

<div id="copyright"> ©apple </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a containing div, [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and the vh and vw declarations in css.

vh determines the view height, so 100vh is 100% of the window. With your assets I've stacked the image on 95% of the screen and the text below on 5%. vw works the same but for view width.

```
.container{
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
 #image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 #copyright{
  height: 5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Here is a codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/danhebdon/pen/vYdmxmv)

Comment: Wow, this is such a perfect answer! Stackoverflow needs more people like you, was just wondering, how do you put the copyright text behind the image in zscore?

Comment: You can use the property z-index, you can read about it [here] (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) but it boils down to
`property {
  z-index: -1;
}`
Note: "z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements)."